# Show measure based on other column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write oracle sql for below scenario. Can anyone provide pointers?

My data is like

[image]

Now whenever a customer has 401k account I have to default the balance to zero else show the total balance.

Thanks,
Pratap

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a `case` expression.

```
select customer,
case when count(case when account='401K' then 1 end) > 0 then 0 else sum(balance) end 
from tbl
group by customer
```